# make copy paste faster excel vba to word

Tags: vba, excel

I´ve been assembling a code, that basically copy paste data from excel to a word table, but is a little bit slow.

And I also noticed, that when I make false the screenupdating and the events, the programs stop, without any number message of error.

I´d like to have your recommendations to speed up the code. Thanks!

```
Sub InspecForm()

'PURPOSE: Copy/Paste An Excel Table Into a New Word Document
'NOTE: Must have Word Object Library Active in Order to Run _
  (VBE > Tools > References > Microsoft Word 12.0 Object Library)
'SOURCE: www.TheSpreadsheetGuru.com

Dim tbl As Excel.Range
Dim WordApp As Word.Application
Dim myDoc As Word.Document
Dim WordTable As Word.Table
Dim rwcll, wrdlct As Integer
Dim lRow, llRow As Long


'Optimize Code
  'Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  'Application.EnableEvents = False

'Copy Range from Excel, Set tbl = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Sheet1.Name).ListObjects("Table1").Range

'Create an Instance of MS Word
  On Error Resume Next

    'Is MS Word already opened?
      Set WordApp = GetObject(class:="Word.Application")

    'Clear the error between errors
      Err.Clear

    'If MS Word is not already open then open MS Word
      If WordApp Is Nothing Then Set WordApp = CreateObject(class:="Word.Application")

    'Handle if the Word Application is not found
      If Err.Number = 429 Then
        MsgBox "Microsoft Word could not be found, aborting."
        GoTo EndRoutine
      End If

  On Error GoTo 0

'Make MS Word Visible and Active
  WordApp.Visible = True
  WordApp.Activate

'Select Document
  Set myDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Generic Inspection Form.docx")

'Variables to control the copy and paste
  rwcll = 2
  wrdlct = 44
  lRow = 2
  llRow = 2

  Worksheets("Receiving List").Range("C" & 2).Copy

            myDoc.Paragraphs(3).Range.PasteExcelTable _
            LinkedToExcel:=False, _
            WordFormatting:=False, _
            RTF:=True



    Do While (Cells(lRow, 1) <> "")

    'Copy Excel Values and Paste on word
          Worksheets("D").Range("A" & rwcll).Copy

          myDoc.Paragraphs(wrdlct).Range.PasteExcelTable _
            LinkedToExcel:=False, _
            WordFormatting:=False, _
            RTF:=True
            wrdlct = wrdlct + 1

    'Copy Excel Values and Paste on word
         Worksheets("D").Range("B" & rwcll).Copy

          myDoc.Paragraphs(wrdlct).Range.PasteExcelTable _
            LinkedToExcel:=False, _
            WordFormatting:=False, _
            RTF:=True

     'Variable for positioning the paste
           rwcll = rwcll + 1
           wrdlct = wrdlct + 9
           lRow = 1 + lRow
           llRow = 1 + llRow

    'Variable for positioning the paste
           If llRow = 17 Then
           wrdlct = wrdlct + 17
           llRow = 0
           End If



    Loop

            lRow = lRow - 2
            Range("G1").Value = lRow

          Worksheets("D").Range("G" & 1).Copy

            myDoc.Paragraphs(9).Range.PasteExcelTable _
            LinkedToExcel:=False, _
            WordFormatting:=False, _
            RTF:=True
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            wrdlct = wrdlct + 1


EndRoutine:
'Optimize Code
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  Application.EnableEvents = True

'Clear The Clipboard
  Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Comment: Remove the comments at `'Application.ScreenUpdating = False` and `'Application.EnableEvents = False`. It should make it a little bit faster

Comment: You're using `On Error Resume Next` - why would you expect an error message?

Comment: @MacroMan That is to trap the error if Word isn't already running.

Comment: @JonPeltier I know, my point is that it's only set up to trap one specific error. There's nothing to handle other errors that might explain the OP's issue.

Comment: Then he puts `On Error GoTo 0` right after the last chance to get an error when starting Word (it also traps the error if Word just can't be started). Any further errors should open the debugger.

Answer (score 1):

At the top of the page add: ***Option Explicit***, which forces you to use variables and speeds it up..
At the end of the code add: ***Application.ScreenUpdating = True***, which speeds it up.